# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'category' of undefined

Tags: angular, typeerror

Hi I'm trying to build a project in angular 6, and am getting an input of categories : Tag[] from a superbar component to a catbar component. Further from catbar I'm furthe trying to pass the strings of categories[0].category and categories[0].superCategory to a feed component.
This is where I'm encountering the error saying that it cannot read property category of undefined. I am unable to  understand this error as in the input decorator I am clearly declaring it as @Input catgories : Tag[]

PFA the code for tag class,catbar.html,catbar.ts and feed.ts::Catbar-->

```
export class CatbarComponent implements OnInit {

private  Catdomain = domain;
@Input() categories: Tag[]; 
//This input might have unfortunate timing

constructor() { }
ngOnInit() {
}
notifyme() {
  console.log('AM here');
}

}
```

catbar.html

```
<div style = "text-align: center">
<nav _ngcontent-c4="" class="navbar-category" style="height: auto">
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let cat of categories" class="li-cat font-preadr cursor-pointer" >
    <div class="li-cat-circle">
       <img [ngClass]="{'li-cat-circle-img': !selectedCat || selectedCat.name !== cat.name, 'selected-cat-img': selectedCat && selectedCat.name === cat.name}"
          [src] = "Catdomain + cat.image"  [title]="cat.displayName">
   </div>
    <div class="li-cat-name" [title]="cat.displayName" [ngClass]="{'selected-cat-name': selectedCat && selectedCat.name === cat.name}">
      {{cat.displayName}}
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
<app-feed [sucat]="categories[0].superCategory" [cat]="categories[0].category"></app-feed>
```

feed.ts-->

```
  @Input() cat :string; 
  @Input() sucat:string;

  private cards : Card[];
  private itemcount : number;
  private lastpage : number;
  constructor(private contentservice: ContentService) { }
  private page :number = 1;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchdata(this.sucat,this.cat);//initial fetch  of data would require 3 default parameters

  }
  fetchdata(su :string,cat : string){
  this.contentservice.getcontentdata(su,cat,this.page)
  .subscribe((response) => {
    const data = new JsonData(response);
    this.cards = data.items;
    this.cards.forEach(el =>{
      console.log(el.title);
    })
    this.page++;
    });
  }
}
```

Tag class-->

```
export class Tag {
   public category: string;
   public description: string;
   public displayName: string;
   public id?: number;
   public name?: string;
   public image?: string;
   public isLive?: boolean;
   public isLiveClient?: boolean;
   public level?: number;
   public shortDisplayName?: string;
   public superCategory?: string;
}
```

The  catgories array is poopulated from superbar as

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-superbar',
  templateUrl: './superbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./superbar.component.css']
})
export class SuperbarComponent implements OnInit {

@ViewChild('child')
private child : CatbarComponent

  supercategories : Tag [] = [];
  allcategories : Tag[] = [];
  categories : Tag[] = [];
  tempCategories : Tag[] = [];
  selectedsu : Tag;

  constructor(private meta : MetadataService) {}
  //using meta data service to get supercategories
  ngOnInit() {
   this.meta.getmetadata().subscribe(response =>{
     //newCatJson requires an object type data
     //in earlier versions one needed to body.parse(), but since http returns an object
     //that no longer needs be done
     const data = new CatJson(response);
     this.supercategories =  data.superCat;
     this.selectedsu = this.supercategories[0];
     this.allcategories = data.allCat;
     this.allcategories.forEach(item => {
          if (this.supercategories[0].superCategory == item.superCategory)
              this.categories.push(item);
      })  
     });

    }
```

and is inputted to catbar as

```
<app-catbar #child [categories]="categories"></app-catbar>
```

Comment: How do you populate the `categories` array?

Comment: The categories array is input to catbar from the superbarcomponent
this.allcategories = data.allCat;
     this.allcategories.forEach(item => {
          if (this.supercategories[0].superCategory == item.superCategory)
              this.categories.push(item);
      })

Comment: Yes, what I meant was, how is the array populated in the parent component?

Comment: Sorry, please view the edit

Comment: Try using the elvis operator: `[cat]="categories[0]?.category"`

Comment: The  operator is  causing the error itself to go away but the cat and sucat strings are holding a value of null :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ng-container](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ngcontainer) & `ngIf` for this kind of situations:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="categories[0]">
<app-feed [sucat]="categories[0].superCategory" [cat]="categories[0].category"></app-feed>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked. Could you maybe tell me as to how tho?

Comment: Like @bugs pointed your array  categories was still undefined when you try to read its value. With this method you wait until its value is available.